# Hard disk sudden failure

Tags: hard-drive

A few days ago i bought a new hard disk for my laptop and decided to keep the old one as a backup storrage device. Since my laptop doesn't have two hard disk slots i bought a special caddy and installed the backup hard disk on the DVD-Writer slot.

Everything went ok, until last night when the backup hard disk suddenly started having problems.

```
Relocated sectors 128
Relocated event count 7
Current pending sectors 512 ( 400 last night )
```

The drive has been online for about 300 days.

[image]

The faulty Hard drive is Toshiba 5400rpm 500gb

Comment: Hard disk is failing. Backup up now and replace the disk.

Comment: I was just wondering if it was my fault somehow. The temperature starts from abt 20C and ends up at abt 33C after a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

33°C is perfectly OK.
Maybe you kind of crashed the drive on the table when you installed it into the caddy.

If you want to know more about failure temperatures:

https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/de//archive/disk_failures.pdf